# Replace a text with all alphabet VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, compilation

I just stopped by this error

```
 System.NullReferenceException was unhandled   HResult=-2147467261  
 Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.  
 Source=System.Windows.Forms   StackTrace:
        at System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox.StreamIn(String str, Int32 flags)
        at System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox.set_SelectedText(String value)
        at Novania_JAV_Viewer_EncDec.Form1.Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs ef) in c:\users\toshiba\documents\visual studio
 2010\Projects\Novania JAV Viewer EncDec\Novania JAV Viewer
 EncDec\Form1.vb:line 91
        at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
        at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
        at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
        at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
        at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
        at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
        at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
        at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
        at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
        at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
        at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
        at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr
 dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
        at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32
 reason, ApplicationContext context)
        at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32
 reason, ApplicationContext context)
        at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(ApplicationContext context)
        at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.OnRun()
        at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.DoApplicationModel()
        at Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.Run(String[]
 commandLine)
        at Novania_JAV_Viewer_EncDec.My.MyApplication.Main(String[] Args) in 17d14f5c-a337-4978-8281-53493378c1071.vb:line 81
        at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
        at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
        at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
        at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
        at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
 executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
 preserveSyncCtx)
        at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
 preserveSyncCtx)
        at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
        at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()   InnerException:
```

and this is my whole code, I am trying to replace all alphabet in one word, and it needs to replace one by one, and one by one variable.

the error is located here ("title") word

```
Do Until RichTextBox1.Find("titelz") = -1
RichTextBox1.Find("titelz")
RichTextBox1.SelectedText = titel
```

and this is my whole form class code

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        RichTextBox1.LoadFile("template.rtf")
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal ef As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim A As String
        Replace(TextBox1.Text, "A", "5TY5")
        Console.WriteLine(A)
        Dim B As String
        Replace(A, "B", "WEE")
        Console.WriteLine(B)
        Dim C As String
        Replace(B, "C", "23RW")
        Console.WriteLine(C)
        Dim D As String
        Replace(C, "D", "RW4R")
        Console.WriteLine(D)
        Dim E As String
        Replace(D, "E", "DFS")
        Console.WriteLine(E)
        Dim F As String
        Replace(E, "F", "R5")
        Console.WriteLine(F)
        Dim G As String
        Replace(F, "G", "QWEDQ")
        Console.WriteLine(G)
        Dim H As String
        Replace(G, "H", "ZDCZ")
        Console.WriteLine(H)
        Dim I As String
        Replace(H, "I", "VGHN")
        Console.WriteLine(I)
        Dim J As String
        Replace(I, "J", "ZSC")
        Console.WriteLine(J)
        Dim K As String
        Replace(J, "K", "ZSD")
        Console.WriteLine(K)
        Dim L As String
        Replace(K, "L", "WER")
        Console.WriteLine(L)
        Dim M As String
        Replace(L, "M", "GN")
        Console.WriteLine(M)
        Dim N As String
        Replace(M, "N", "xfv")
        Console.WriteLine(N)
        Dim O As String
        Replace(N, "O", "DAASAD")
        Console.WriteLine(O)
        Dim P As String
        Replace(O, "P", "WET")
        Console.WriteLine(P)
        Dim Q As String
        Replace(P, "Q", "DFCV")
        Console.WriteLine(Q)
        Dim R As String
        Replace(Q, "R", "ADSDA")
        Console.WriteLine(R)
        Dim S As String
        Replace(R, "S", "SGFDG")
        Console.WriteLine(S)
        Dim T As String
        Replace(S, "T", "SFSFD")
        Console.WriteLine(T)
        Dim U As String
        Replace(T, "U", "AWDAD")
        Console.WriteLine(U)
        Dim V As String
        Replace(U, "V", "RERE")
        Console.WriteLine(V)
        Dim W As String
        Replace(V, "W", "GBGDBB")
        Console.WriteLine(W)
        Dim X As String
        Replace(W, "X", " AWDAW ")
        Console.WriteLine(X)
        Dim Y As String
        Replace(X, "Y", "AWDEAVA")
        Console.WriteLine(Y)
        Dim Z As String
        Replace(Y, "Z", "AWEDWADW")
        Console.WriteLine(Z)
        Dim titel As String = Z

        Do Until RichTextBox1.Find("titelz") = -1
            RichTextBox1.Find("titelz")
            RichTextBox1.SelectedText = titel
        Loop
        RichTextBox2.Text = RichTextBox1.Text
        RichTextBox1.Clear()
        RichTextBox1.LoadFile("template.rtf")
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: `Replace(TextBox1.Text, "A", "5TY5")` --> `RichTextBox1.Text`?

Comment: Although I'm not sure what this code is supposed to do... You should name your controls a bit better. (Code comments are also useful sometimes)

Comment: the code is for replacing a word or a string contains the caps alphabets inti a word. The problem is at the end of the replace, the value "titel" is error ("titel = Z")

Answer (score 0):

In order to do the replace, I'd try the following code...
It uses a **Dictionary** type variable. They are used in .NET quite a lot as some sort of associative array.

```
' First, create dictionary that you can loop through.
' This variable is created on form level (so only once)
' and contains all the "words" as key-value pairs.
' So you can search for key and replace with value.
Dim replaceDictionary As New Dictionary(Of String, String) From {{"A", "5TY5"}, _
                                                                 {"B", "WEE"}, _
                                                                 {"C", "23RW"}, _
                                                                 {"D", "RW4R"}, _
                                                                 {"E", "DFS"}, _
                                                                 {"F", "R5"}, _
                                                                 {"G", "QWEDQ"}, _
                                                                 {"H", "ZDCZ"}, _
                                                                 {"I", "VGHN"}, _
                                                                 {"J", "ZSC"}, _
                                                                 {"K", "ZSD"}, _
                                                                 {"L", "WER"}, _
                                                                 {"M", "GN"}, _
                                                                 {"N", "xfv"}, _
                                                                 {"O", "DAASAD"}, _
                                                                 {"P", "WET"}, _
                                                                 {"Q", "DFCV"}, _
                                                                 {"R", "ADSDA"}, _
                                                                 {"S", "SGFDG"}, _
                                                                 {"T", "SFSFD"}, _
                                                                 {"U", "AWDAD"}, _
                                                                 {"V", "RERE"}, _
                                                                 {"W", "GBGDBB"}, _
                                                                 {"X", " AWDAW "}, _
                                                                 {"Y", "AWDEAVA"}, _
                                                                 {"Z", "AWEDWADW"}
                                                                }

Private Sub btnReplace_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnReplace.Click
    ' Declare temporary variable to store text
    Dim tmpText As String = txtTitel.Text

    ' Loop through dictionary
    For Each replaceItem In replaceDictionary
        ' Replace key ("A" etc.) with value ("5TY5" etc.)
        ' and store in temporary variable
        tmpText = Replace(tmpText, replaceItem.Key, replaceItem.Value)
    Next

    'Display text
    txtTitel.Text = tmpText
End Sub
```

Now for your "find" part... nothing like `"titelz"` is going to be changed with above code (only caps), so if it was in there, it stays in there.
So I have no idea what to do with that...

**Edit**

For the record: this goes for a long line of replaces... Once you've replaced all the `A`'s in your string, the `T` from `"5TY5"` will also be replaced.
If you don't want this, you'll have to split the original text into characters and start checking them one by one.

---

### Checking title string one letter at a time

There are a few changes to above code:

- Dictionary is now of type (Char, String) instead of 2 strings.
- The title is stored in a seperate variable in order to keep working with the orignal title text.
- Instead of looping through the dictionary, you loop through the title text one letter at a time.

The code is documented with comments and should be pretty self-explanatory.

Good luck!

```
' First, create dictionary that you can loop through.
' This variable is created on form level (so only once)
' and contains all the "words" as key-value pairs.
' So you can search for key and replace with value.
Dim replaceDictionary As New Dictionary(Of Char, String) From {{"A", "5TY5"}, _
                                                               {"B", "WEE"}, _
                                                               {"C", "23RW"}, _
                                                               {"D", "RW4R"}, _
                                                               {"E", "DFS"}, _
                                                               {"F", "R5"}, _
                                                               {"G", "QWEDQ"}, _
                                                               {"H", "ZDCZ"}, _
                                                               {"I", "VGHN"}, _
                                                               {"J", "ZSC"}, _
                                                               {"K", "ZSD"}, _
                                                               {"L", "WER"}, _
                                                               {"M", "GN"}, _
                                                               {"N", "xfv"}, _
                                                               {"O", "DAASAD"}, _
                                                               {"P", "WET"}, _
                                                               {"Q", "DFCV"}, _
                                                               {"R", "ADSDA"}, _
                                                               {"S", "SGFDG"}, _
                                                               {"T", "SFSFD"}, _
                                                               {"U", "AWDAD"}, _
                                                               {"V", "RERE"}, _
                                                               {"W", "GBGDBB"}, _
                                                               {"X", " AWDAW "}, _
                                                               {"Y", "AWDEAVA"}, _
                                                               {"Z", "AWEDWADW"}
                                                              }

Private Sub btnReplace_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnReplace.Click
    ' Declare temporary variable to store text
    Dim tmpTitle As String = txtTitel.Text
    Dim tmpText As String = ""
    Dim tmpLetter As Char

    ' Loop through title string
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    Do While (i < tmpTitle.Length)
        ' Increase counter
        i += 1

        ' Save next letter in tmpLetter
        tmpLetter = Mid(tmpTitle, i, 1)

        ' Check for key in dictionary
        If replaceDictionary.ContainsKey(tmpLetter) Then
            ' When found, append associated value to tmpText
            tmpText &= replaceDictionary(tmpLetter)
        Else
            ' Not found: use letter from title string
            tmpText &= CStr(tmpLetter)
        End If

    Loop

    'Display text
    txtTitel.Text = tmpText
End Sub
```

Comment: wow so it would be the same with the result of my code, they will replace once another replaced, but thanks Mart, I appreciate it :)

Comment: I forgot, if any one have another way to replace for each character, it would be nice, I have and idea, how if I xhange the textbox into richtextbox? so will the "richtextbox.find" and some looping of it, will replace for every character for each of them?

I mean like

            Do Until RichTextbox1.Find("A") = -1
                RichTextbox1.Find("A")
                RichTextbox1.SelectedText = "5TY5"
            Loop

Comment: My code works with both a regular TextBox-control and a RichTextBox-control. - I have a way to check each character only once (using a `Do While` loop and the [`Mid()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3sh1xas1.aspx)-function). Should you want to try it yourself first, be my guest. I'll post an update tomorrow.

Comment: i am so confuse with this, logically  I need to separate each character from a string, then replace each of them, and then combine it again. The count of character must be done with Len("string"), so Do While will need this, say i= Len("string"), and 

Do While not i = 0
 "Replacement Key"

Comment: Okay I'll try tomorrow, Thanks Marty
soon I will tell you if this works for me :)

Comment: Not at all. `Length` is now a property of any string value. You don't need the `Len()` function.